# The Healing at the Pool in John 5:1-14

Tags: john, healing

What is the significance of the man's belief regarding healing through the disturbed waters?

1. Was it just a belief (bordering on superstition)?
2. Or was it really intended by God for healing to take place in such a way?

   Probably similar to the bronze snake in `Numbers 21:4-8`.

   Quoted the bronze snake not for identical comparison, but only to show that such healings were ordained by God. But I think Bronze snake is a very special circumstance, and as it is a typology of Christ on the cross.

Why I raised this question is that if it is really ordained by God for healing to take place in this manner, it somehow sounded unfair to restrict healing only to the first person who gets into pool as soon as waters are disturbed.

Answer (score 3):

If one were to base their interpretation solely off the text, the narrative states (NASB):

> In these lay a multitude of those who 
>   were sick, blind, lame, and withered, 
>   [waiting for the moving of the waters; 
>   4 for an angel of the Lord went down 
>   at certain seasons into the pool and 
>   stirred up the water; whoever then 
>   first, after the stirring up of the 
>   water, stepped in was made well from 
>   whatever disease with which he was 
>   afflicted.]
>
> John 5:3-4

In versions such as the KJV and NASB,  while other translations choose to omit it, it says "an angel of the Lord".

Further, following the narrative, one would be led to think that a man who had sat already for 38 years would have discovered whether or not the thing was a hoax.  If, after 10 years, say, no one had ever been healed, he would have moved to a better place to beg.

And, finally, Jesus seemed impressed and only approached him when He heard that the man had been there for such a long time.  Certainly, he would have seen the man.  And, it was only after He heard about him that He acted.  This, and the fact that He didn't discredit the pool or the man beside it, lends to its authenticity, textually.

As for "fairness", I can only note the prophets and writings.  Who are you, oh man?  Who let you vote on "fair"?  Will the vessel say to the potter what are you making? And, what is better, to heal one, or dry up the pool altogether?  Our debates about fairness, not knowing the situation, is apt to bring reminders of Namaan, the Syrian healed, when there were many lepers in Israel.  Or, the widow in Zarepath.  Or, Noah and his boys.

Besides, if the pool worked that well, what would Jesus have had left to do when he got there?

Comment: Good argument; it explains how others were healed and the impotent man wasn't. The fact is there is healing under the Old Covenant-what was missing is the Person of the Healer, which the OP alluded to.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we should look at the history of this passage. When we read the Bible, it says (KJV John 5:2-7):

> Now there is at Jerusalem by the sheep market a pool, which is called in the Hebrew tongue Bethesda, having five porches. In these lay a great multitude of impotent folk, of blind, halt, withered, waiting for the moving of the water. ***For an angel went down at a certain season into the pool, and troubled the water: whosoever then first after the troubling of the water stepped in was made whole of whatsoever disease he had.*** And a certain man was there, which had an infirmity thirty and eight years. When Jesus saw him lie, and knew that he had been now a long time in that case, he saith unto him, Wilt thou be made whole? The impotent man answered him, Sir, I have no man, when the water is troubled, to put me into the pool: but while I am coming, another steppeth down before me.

I have highlighted verse 5:4 in the above passage, because it is generally regarded as a later interpolation, and is omitted from the United Bible Societies New Testament, 4th Edition, 1993 (UBS4).

Now we need to understand why the man believed he could be cured by entering the waters, which he seems to have regarded as confirmed by others who were more more mobile and able to enter the water before he could. Archaeologists have found a pool that corresponds to John's description, and have found evidence of an Asclepium, or temple to the Greek god of healing, Asclepius. This would explain why the pool was at such a malodorous place as a sheep market, outside the city wall, since a pagan temple was not allowed inside Jerusalem. It is also known that Asclepia had pools which the god would occasionally come by and disturb the waters, so that the first to enter the water would be cured.

Although the gospel says that the man was a Jew, he is portrayed as so desperate that he would try anything, even seeking help from a pagan god.

The likely significance of this passage is provided by Wikipedia, which says (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_of_Bethesda):

> "Some scholars have suggested that the narrative is actually part of a deliberate polemic against the Asclepius cult, an antagonism possibly partly brought on by the fact that Asclepius was worshipped as Saviour (Greek: Soter), in reference to his healing attributes"

Comment: Thanks. So it is highly likely that this has a non-Jewish background, and likely to be from Greek belief. Can we safely assume that it is not endorsed by the gospel writer but just reported as a matter of the prevalant belief?

Comment: I side with Wikipedia's sources on this, although I would probably go into several pages to more fully explain why. When Wiki says "Some scholars have suggested that the narrative is actually part of a deliberate polemic against the Asclepius cult, an antagonism possibly partly brought on by the fact that Asclepius was worshipped as Saviour (Greek: Soter), in reference to his healing attributes" they are atributing this polemic to the evangelist - he endorsed it. Either way, we agree that the event did not occur.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I would like to confirm: you believe that the entire incident of such healing did not happen? (not just the `second part of verse 3 to verse 4` which you have highlighted as bold in your ref to scriptures). And your conclusion was based on the references cited in the Wiki article. Is my understanding correct about your position?

Comment: I do believe the incident did not happen, but I do not base my conclusion on Wikipedia. I acknowledge that Wikipedia does get things wrong, although in this case there is a citation, but one I can not vouch for. I think at the more professional level we aim for here that too much reliance on Wikipedia would be foolish, but since I believe that statement to be reasonably correct, I cited it as an accessible online source.

Comment: Perhaps I should use Occam's Razor and say no more, or write the several pages I mentioned above would be necessary to explain in full. But fool step in ...  You may know that John's Gospel was originally anonymous and was speculatively attributed to John rather late in the second century, for reasons I will not go into.  You may also know that the consensus of critical scholars is that the author was not an eyewitness to the mission of Jesus. There are several 'political' passages in John, and this is one of them. That last sentence is only'guilt by association', but it is a powerful one here

Comment: @DickHarfield OK, so you are going to attribute to a pagan god healing, which only the God of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob are capable of(Ex. 15:26); and the ministry of Jesus affirmed. I don't think so, nor can you lend credence to any Evangelist citing this. So much for Post-Modernist interpretation....

Comment: @user2479: This is not my attribution. I have cited experts. Let me then cite John Dominic Crossan, who states in 'The Birth of Christianity' (page 297) that he visited the asclepium at Epidaurus in Greece and was struck by the general similarity between the ailments involved in stories of healing there and at Lourdes and Fatima. He says real people with real ailments – including paralysis, blindness, deafness, dumbness, growths and wounds – were clearly healed at Epidaurus. Crossan is no fly-by-night, described as "the premier historical Jesus scholar in the world.”

Comment: @ulmo: If Richard Baukham is convinced, against the views of many other eminent scholars, that John was written by the apostle John, is it possible that he is "a little too confident?" It was only in an explanatory note that I said this, using the words "may know" - which does not seem like overconfidence. Others may rely on Baukham's research, but I think the weight of evidence is against him.

Comment: @DickHarfield "Out of his study of cross-attestation and strata of the ancient texts, Crossan asserts that many of the gospel stories of Jesus are not factual, including his "nature miracles", the virgin birth, and the raising of Lazarus. Crossan takes the opposite view, that Jesus was known during earliest Christianity as a powerful magician, which was "a very problematic and controversial phenomenon not only for his enemies but even for his friends," who began washing miracles out of the tradition early on."(Wikipedia) False pre-suppositions lead to false conclusions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not buy every book that comes on to the market, but I did find that Jesus and the Eyewitnesses is available online. It is poorly formatted and lacks page numbers, so it is hard to read and reference, but adequate.  I focussed on the identity of the author, and cite the following, hopefully in context. The Identity of the Beloved Disciple. “Argued that the Gospel of John portrays and claims as its author the disciple it calls “the disciple Jesus loved,” and that this claim to authorship is plausibly authentic.” Note # Plausibly authenticity is OK but not good enough. <CONT>

Comment: <CONT> “This argument has also entailed supposing that the Beloved Disciple was not one of the Twelve, but a lesser known disciple, not known from the Gospel traditions generally, a disciple who had to establish his claim to a role of privileged witness to Jesus in the minds of readers or hearers who may well know nothing about him.” #Kills the claim of John Zebedee stone dead! <CONT>

Comment: <CONT> “All this suggests that the distinctive narratives of the Gospel of John derive not simply from the Beloved Disciple himself, but from a particular circle of disciples of Jesus in which the Beloved Disciple moved.” #Which side is Bauckham on? <CONT>

Comment: <CONT> “Could John the Elder have been the Beloved Disciple and the author of the Gospel of John?” # This is how you introduce a speculative argument, not a challenging one. “If, as I believe, the same author was responsible for the Gospel of John and all three Johannine letters, then our argument leads to the conclusion that John the Elder was the Beloved Disciple and the author of the Gospel of John.”  ## @ulmo , I am afraid I give no credence to speculative scholarship like this. I prefer sources that give sound, reasoned arguments. ##

Comment: @Tau You will be surprised to learn that a growing number of scholars see Jesus' nature miracles, virgin birth and raising of Lazarus as not factual, to the point that Crossan is becoming mainstream on this. Nevertheless you must have noticed that I did not cite Crossan in my answer, so any criticism of him should not be a criticism of my answer.

Comment: @DickHarfield To attribute to 'magic' or the devil the works of God is blasphemous(Mark 3:28-30) Verily I say unto you, All sins shall be forgiven unto the sons of men, and blasphemies wherewith soever they shall blaspheme:
29 But he that shall blaspheme against the Holy Ghost hath never forgiveness, but is in danger of eternal damnation:
30 Because they said, He hath an unclean spirit." If the authors of the text stated that "an angel troubled(stirred up) the waters, why would Jesus endorse what He already expressly prohibited? This is an example of "Post-Modern" textual criticism.

Comment: @tau: This site is dedicated to hermeneutics and the opinions and research of others should be respected without accusations of blasphemy. In any case, the point was made above, that this event did not really occur, and therefore Jesus did not endorse Asclepius. As Wikipedia says, the author of John was engaging in a "deliberate polemic against the Asclepius cult."

Comment: @DickHarfield Now I am really confused; do we take the text as it was written, or do we ignore the text for research which may or may not suggest the event took place? I am not accusing the researchers of blasphemy, I am merely stating that attributing the works of God to the devil are considered blasphemous-Jesus Himself says so. To find something in the language previously unknown which suggests the intent of the author is good hermeneutics; to rely on pagan references to determine the veracity of the text is to demean the text itself.

Comment: @tau I am saying that the best NT researchers (in my view) do not say that everything described in the gospels actually happened just as the gospels say. I already pointed out in my answer that a key verse is not included in the original text. The gospel was written anonymously and appears to have undergone some further changes. No matter who wrote it, he was unlikely to have been an eyewitness. How would he have known what Jesus did? Why did the earlier gospel authors not know of this important miracle? Hermeneutics means looking at the text to see what it really means, which is what I did.

Comment: No one suggests that Asclepius truly heals people. Crossan, whom I cited in a note, speaks for other scholars in saying it was not Asclepius who heals people, but their strongly held faith in Asclepius. Faith can work apparent miracles, even when the god does not exist.